# Booked and boarding station differ; can we board from the booking station?

Tags: trains, india, rajasthan, chennai

I have booked a ticked from Kota to Chennai and mention boarding from Ujjain. Can I travel from Kota? Is there any penalty, or do we have to go for a boarding change?

Comment: I know it's not the same case but it seems as if you booked a train from Delhi to Mumbai from Bangalore and now you want to board from Bangalore. Although I believe that your train stops at Ujjain and Kota both. Does the train stop at Kota first or Ujjain first?

Comment: Okay so obviously the train stops at Kota first (Google Maps). So that basically means that you've paid for the fare from Ujjain to Chennai and not between Kota to Ujjain. I'm not sure but I think you need to change your ticket.